# Filtering the 4 most frequently read articles in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm currently building a blog with Django. I have the following blog post model. I want to select 4 most read articles because this section in the `HTML` file has only 4 posts. How can i do this please ? Thank you

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_category = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)

    author = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    content = models.TextField(null=False, default="")

    post_slug = models.SlugField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    number_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)  #number of views 
    post_image = models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order by the `number_views` and then select the first four:

```
#                               first four ↓
BlogPost.objects.order_by('-number_views')[:4]
```